# How can I trigger the click from inside a user generated event?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's assume that I have code shown below. `this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();` doesn't work because it is triggered by `sendMessage` and it is not triggered directly by user action but I need to use response from `sendMessage` to check whether `data.uploading` is equals to True. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this?

navbar.component.html:

```
      <li class='nav-item sidebar-false-upload' *ngIf="isCloud() && !sidebarVisible">
<label #fileInput (click)="this.uploadFile()" data-toggle="collapse"
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="pretty-file nav-link" ><i
          class="nc-icon nc-cloud-upload-94"></i>Upload

                  <div id="fileSelector" >
                      <input type="file" name="fileUplaod" id="fileUpload"
                      multiple ng2FileSelect [uploader]="this.UploaderService.uploader" >
                  </div>
  </label>
      </li>
```

navbar.component.ts:

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  message:string;
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private http: Http, public location: Location, private element: ElementRef, private data: DataService, private UserService: UserService, private UploaderService: UploaderService) {
  }

keyDownFunction(term:string, event) {

  if(event.keyCode == 13) {

    this.UserService.sendMessage(term, localStorage.getItem('current_path')  + '/').subscribe((data : any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('message', data.message);
      localStorage.setItem('path', data.path);

      if (data.uploading == 'True')
      {
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
      }
      else if (data.downloading == 'True')
      {
       // it is just an example, I wanted to show that I have more options than uploading and downloading so I have to check response from sendMessage in variable data.
      }
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.error)
    alert(err.error)
  });

  }
}
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
sendMessage(message: string, path: string) {

    const data = {
      message: message,
      path: path
    }

    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',  'Authorization': 'token ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken') });

    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + localStorage.getItem('path'), data, { headers: reqHeader});

  }
```

So as I have mentioned and as you can see above the problem is associated with `sendMessage`. I need this to get `data.variable` in order to check what I have to execute but on the other hand `this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();` doesn't work because it is not action directly executed by the user. When I call `this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();` directly after `if(event.keyCode == 13) {` it works properly however I am not able whether I want to execute this action. If something is unclear or you need some more information just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it the 4th time that you ask this question, after deleting the previous one?

Comment: Please limit your tags to only those relevant to your post. AngularJS is a different framework from Angular, and `angular6` should be used for questions specific to that version. Following that logic, it doesn't make sense to also tag a question `angular7`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your click command in this:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    .click() command
});
```

this.ngZone comes from your constructor and you need to add private ngZone: NgZone to your constructor.

The reason is because your async function isnt being picked up by angular. This will force it to be.

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  message:string;
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private http: Http, public location: Location, private element: ElementRef, private data: DataService, private UserService: UserService, private UploaderService: UploaderService, private zone: NgZone) {
  }

keyDownFunction(term:string, event) {

  if(event.keyCode == 13) {

    this.UserService.sendMessage(term, localStorage.getItem('current_path')  + '/').subscribe((data : any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('message', data.message);
      localStorage.setItem('path', data.path);

      if (data.uploading == 'True')
      {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
        });
      }
      else if (data.downloading == 'True')
      {
       // it is just an example, I wanted to show that I have more options than uploading and downloading so I have to check response from sendMessage in variable data.
      }
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.error)
    alert(err.error)
  });

  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Do you mean `this.zone.run(() => {

  uploadFile() { function body });

}`?

Comment: No in your response you run the zone.run command.  If makes angular recognize that what you are about to do in this loop needs to update the UI.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well what doesn't work, not really sure whats not working.  Are you sure that your code is hitting properly?  if (data.uploading == 'True') is true? Why are you using 'True' and not true as an actual value.  Why is it a string?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is hitting this code because I have `if (data.uploading == 'True') {

            console.log('data uploading')

              this.zone.run(() => {
            this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
        });


          }` I have True because I get this value from backend in JSON.

Comment: Are you sure that your .click() is working correctly? Looks like you have a click event on a label.  I think that you need to change <label> to <button> so it has a real click event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185275/discussion-between-user1779362-and-thedbogh).